# Beginner having trouble using mocking frameworks C# .net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, moq

I am a student on a work placement. I have been given the task of finishing an app, then testing.

The app is done, and I have tested 80 %. However, I have some methods that are not directly testable as they use session vars and form requests. I understand that I need to use a mocking framework, and chose to go with moq, as from what I have read it is awesome. Unfortunately, I've played around with it and find it a bit over my head (I'm new to C# in general, including lambdas, etc.)

I haven't been able to find a simplified beginners walkthrough. Any ideas where I could find such a thing? As I said, all I need is to be able to mock session and forms. All attempts thus far have consisted of me (in a futile manner) plugging in random code found here on SO, and hoping for the best.

I would much rather understand it so I can truly work with it....

Thanks!

Comment: One thing that helped me "get" expressions when I first started learning about them was when I realized that they're not always executed.  For example, `x => x.MyProperty = 5` doesn't just mean what it says.  The expression formed from that statement is a special type of object that can be analyzed at run-time, so that a program can say "Okay, I receive an argument `x`, and then I'm supposed to pass the setter for `MyProperty` a value of 5."  That's how Moq uses them -- it doesn't actually execute the code, it just analyzes it to see what properties/methods you're interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found these tutorials which go over the basics. I don't think there would be anything covering basic C# concepts alongside the Moq framework. If you are getting stuck on things like lambdas it shouldn't be too hard to find a beginners tutorial. I've added a couple of links for lambda tutorials below.

You might also want to try making some simple prototypes of what you want to do before attempting a full solution for the main application. This will let you play around with the concepts without having to worry about the details of the application.

http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart

http://andrewblogs.com/blog/moq-testing-tutorial/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/03/lambda-expressions.aspx

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-the-lambda-operator

Comment: I was just reading the first link, but have never seen the second, and it looks great! As for the lambdas, etc., I am fairly sure I can figure that stuff out... I have also found this: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/To-mock-or-not-to-mock-that-is-the-question-Part-1.aspx , which is not just for moq, but is also helpful. Thanks a bunch!